# Using Json Path to read an unusual property name

Tags: json, kettle, jsonpath

I am working on a kettle program that receives a JSON and must read in multiple company names from the JSON.

Kettle has a tool that allows the developer to use the JSON path to acquire properties, however some of the properties (including the one that I need) are in an unusual format of something.something.

```
  {
    "email": "customeremail@foobar.net",
    "customer.name": "customer name",
    "customer.company": "customer company",
          ...
   }
```

I want to know how I can acquire a property that is written this way.

I'm looking for something akin to $.layer1.layer2[*].(customer.company)

Comment: I've found  JsonPath.read(json, "$.['foo.bar'].key  used as an escape for the dot, but I'm not using javascript to read in the json.

Comment: I think achieving this will be slightly difficult, since the attribute value "customer.company" will be treated as a PATH and not as a value. So one way is to replace the "." with "_" or someother character in kettle.!!!